# To dispaly the image from the array

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to display the image from an array containing 2 variables called `img`  and `value`. I am able to display the `value` but not the `img`(i,e image)  as in below image:

what's wrong in the template??.

Below is the code

**HTML**

```
   <div class="container" *ngFor="let dog of dogs">

        <div class="section">
            <p id="name">Dogs:</p>
            <img   class="dog-img"  src="{{dog.image }}" >
            <span>{{dog.value }}</span>         
        </div>

</div>
```

TS

```
   import { Component, OnInit, VERSION, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
   export interface IDogs {
      img: string;
      value: string;
     }

   @Component({
    selector: 'app-selection-list',
    templateUrl: './selection-list.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./selection-list.component.css']
     })

  export class SelectionListComponent{

  public dogs: IDogs[] =
    [
     {
       img:'https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg',
       value:'dog1',
     },
    {
      img:'https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg',
      value:'dog2',
     },
   ];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should be -

```
<img class="dog-img"  [src]="dog?.img" >
```

You are using `dog.image` whereas property name is `img` in object.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect property name.

```
<img class="dog-img"  src="{{dog.img}}">
```